# How to pass something with apostrophe to json

Tags: php, json, escaping

My facebook app uses facebook's ui method, to which you pass json. My php variable's however might contain apostrophe's... what is the best way to preserve them, while properly passing them to the fb method?

```
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: '<? echo $tname; ?>',
        link: '<? echo $short; ?>',
        caption: '<? echo $description; ?>'
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$myJSON = array(
    'method'      => 'feed',
    'name'        => $tag_line.' at '.$owner_name,
    'link'        => $short,
    'caption'     => $description,
    'description' => $short
);

$myJSON = json_encode($myJSON);
```

`$myJSON` is now contains a string with your data in JSON format and ready to echo to the page.

```
{
    "method"      : "feed",
    "name"        : "tag_line at owner_name",
    "link"        : "short",
    "caption"     : "description",
    "description" : "short"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to "escape" them, meaning add a backslash before them.

There are some convenience functions in PHP to help you accomplish this: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) (specifically for properly formatting JSON) or [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

However, you should use `json_encode` rather than `addslashes` in this case, since `addslashes` *may* output incorrect formatting for JSON depending on the input.

Comment: addslashes is *very* bad advice.

Comment: @Tomalak It's true that it's not a good function for JSON (since `'` shouldn't actually be escaped), but it *does* accomplish what the question is asking. I'll reorder my answer.

Comment: "Close enough" is not an argument. addslashes is the wrong thing to use, especially when there is a dedicated function for the purpose. It's not even *close* to what the OP needs, because - even with nicely escaped strings - what he has is not JSON.

Comment: @Tomalak - why is it so bad? I'm pretty new to this (obviously)

Comment: @Andypandy JSON technically doesn't allow using single quotes for strings. They should be double quotes. But addslashes will still escape single quotes, resulting in something like `"\'"` which is obviously not the intended behaviour.

Comment: @jli addslashes actually worked fine... is there a security concern?

Comment: @Andypandy It's just "technically invalid JSON", and not all parsers are guaranteed to read it. Just like you can have invalid HTML and some browsers can read it, despite it being incorrect.

Comment: @Andypandy: JSON rules are a little more complex than *"oh, just let's escape the quotes and all is well"*. That's why they have a specific function for this, after all. *"It works on my machine"* is not a valid excuse. Not using a dedicated function that's right at your fingertips is not excusable either. As a developer, you are supposed to do things *right*, not to hack away until it kinda works. Also, using `addshlashes` encourages to build JSON from strings, while you are supposed to build JSON from an actual data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The OP needs to escape apostrophes - something that json_encode does not do. The problem that is often encountered is that a json string needs to be generated in php using json_encode and placed in javascript code (as in OP example). Since Javascript does not have heredoc comments you will need to either escape apostrophes or double quotes in order to prevent a parse error.

Something such as:

```
jQuery.parseJSON('<?=str_replace("'", "\\\\u0027", json_encode(array('something' => "John's")))?>');
```

But event this is not optimal as it will sometimes stay as \u0027 on js side. So ideally we need to replace whatever code we used to translate our quote using js again:

```
var code = '<?=parse(json_encode($data)) ?>';
code = code.replace(/\\\\u0027/g, "'");
jQuery.parseJSON(code);
```